# CE Cache - blank pages

Tags: cache, ce-cache

Is anyone experiencing issues with CE Cache lately?  Several sites with CE Cache installed and using static caching have suddenly shown white pages with the {exp:ce_cache:stat:ic} on the page.

It's the same on all sites, the page is blank, clearing the cache brings the page back, at which point it's cached again and refreshing the page brings the white page again.  These sites were working correctly untill recently.

It's happening on sites with different versions of EE and CE Cache.

Removing the {exp:ce_cache:stat:ic} tag fixes the issue.

The versions of CE Cache in use on these sites are: 1.7.2 and 1.10.1

Thanks,

Comment: Since these are cached to flat files, is it possible something changed with the directories they're stored in?

Comment: Hi Romans, thanks for your help.  I don't think so, nothings changed on these site, some haven't being touched for months and they all seemed to fail simultaneously. It also happened on a new site when I tried to set up static caching.  I wonder was it the recent PHP update that caused it?  I guess the developers would be the best people  to ask about that

Comment: It's possible server updates by the host caused the folders where the ce cache files are stored to be unwritable, either because of permissions or maybe they were assigned to another user. I've had this happen to me.